# "update-alternatives" tries to allocate 184467440715620679668 bytes

Tags: apt, package-management, mysql

I tried to install `mysql-server` on my `yakkety` ubuntu laptop and found very annoying problem. I checked that DEB is not corrupted and my `/var/lib/mysql` and `/etc/mysql` are empty,.. but still.

If i do `apt install`, system hangs completely with no unusual message, before install has finished (see UPDATE)

**`dpkg --configure -a` fails after trying to allocate too large memory chunk by post-install script**:

[image]
*Sorry* for posting screenshot

Using `apt purge` works fine. But doesn't resolve the problem.

```
Linux ubuntu 4.8.0-59-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 29 19:38:34 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What can be the solution? **How to get some log or etc to trace/find reason?**

I need this system.

**UPDATE**: I see now leaking memory occurs after specific log message (during `apt install mysql-server`):

```
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
```

No messages appear after this one. It takes some seconds before allocation reaches last available RAM and system hangs

Comment: Did you tried to `sudo apt install -f` ?

Comment: Yes, it restarts installation of `mysql-server-5.7` and causes system/installation to fail again th same way. I can cancel it by editing apt database but installing package again causes the same problem...